# Maven error: Could not transfer artifact: ArtifactTransferException

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, eclipse, maven, sts

I user Spring Tool Suite 4 to build a Spring boot project. When I try to specify dependency MySQL JDBC driver, I got this error:

Could not transfer artifact com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:jar:8.0.31 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect timed out

org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:jar:8.0.31 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect timed out

The first I use these code:

```
        <dependency>
              <groupId>mysql</groupId>
              <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>           
        </dependency>
```

And after that I found this guide https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/post/mysql-connectorj-has-new-maven-coordinates so I change to

```
        <dependency>
              <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
              <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>              
              <version>8.0.31</version>           
        </dependency>
```

but it still does not work.

Please help me! It took me a lot of time.

Comment: Network issue: : Connect timed out. No access allowed to central repository...wrong firewall/proxy definition/configuration..

Comment: The first you had is the right one, not the second one. That being said the fact that you receive a connection time out indicates an issue in your network. Probably a firewall or proxy issue.

Comment: Do you have any mirrors defined in your `~/.m2/settings.xml`? and can you curl the repo from your machine normally i.e something like `curl -i https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/8.0.31/mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.pom`